# python or bash - adding " at beginning of line and ", at end of line

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have text file with something like

```
first line
line nr 2
line three
```

etc

And i want to generate

```
"first line",
"line nr 2",
"line three",
```

I wonder how to do this in python or maybe in bash if it's easier/quicker. I know there is different code for opening file and different for reading only one line in python(?) but i'm not sure which option to use in this case and, more importantly, how to add these characters. Any advice would help.

Comment: What do you want to do with that output? To put it in a list variable in your programming language? To print it to the screen? To write it back to file?

Comment: either write back to file or print to screen... i'll later want to copy and paste this somewhere else so both writing back to the same file or printing to screem are fine as far as i can efficiently copy and paste it later 'manually'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of easy ways to do it...

A simple perl oneliner:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(.*)$/\"$1\",/g' /path/to/your/file
```

To explain a bit, the regex `^(.*)$` grabs everything (the `(.*)`) between the start of the line (`^`) and the end of the line (`$`), then uses the `$1` match group variable to reconstruct it with the quotes and comma.

Comment: ...where it outputs it? to this file or screen?

Comment: `perl -pli -e '$_=qq{"$_"}'` would also do the job.

Answer (score 8):

```
sed 's/.*/"&",/'
```

Comment: I think you want to move the comma after the quote mark; other than that, neat answer!

Comment: `sed 's/.*/"&",/' input_file | xclip`

Answer (score 6):

For the reference, in case someone wants to do the same thing using python. There is a handy module [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) that could be used like this:

```
import fileinput
import sys, os

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True):
    sys.stdout.write('"%s",%s' % (line.rstrip(os.linesep), os.linesep))
```

Then run this as a script:

```
python myscript.py file1 file2 file3
```

That will change the files inplace for you.

Comment: That's the spirit, why use a gnu when you could use a python! +1 for the very handy fileinput module.

Answer (score 6):

Be a true unix geek: use sed!

```
sed 's/^/"/; s/$/",/;' < your_text_file
```

If you want to escape existing double quotes with backslashes, use `'s/"/\\"/g; s/^/"/; s/$/",/;'` as the pattern.

[sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) is ideally suited for this type of task. Check out a ludicrously long [list of examples](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt).

Comment: There's no need for redirection, `sed` accepts the filename as an argument.

Answer (score 5):

there is no need to construct regular expression(with backreferencing) for this task. Its an expensive operation since you are not going to change something in the line. Easiest way is just to print them out.

```
    awk '{print "\042"$0"\042,"}' file
```

Results on operation on a big file:

```
$ head -5 file
this is line
this is line
this is line
this is line
this is line
$ wc -l < file
9545088

$ time  awk '{print "\042"$0"\042,"}' file  >/dev/null

real    0m15.574s
user    0m15.327s
sys     0m0.172s

$ time sed 's/.*/"&",/' file > /dev/null

real    0m31.717s
user    0m31.465s
sys     0m0.157s

$ time perl -p -e 's/^(.*)$/\"$1\",/g'  file >/dev/null

real    0m36.576s
user    0m36.006s
sys     0m0.360s
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash:

```
while read line
    do
    echo "\"${line}\","
done < inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Python

```
for line in open("file"):
  line=line.strip()
  print '"%s",'  % line
```

Answer (score 0):

sh + awk are nice here too...

```
!/bin/sh
for FILE in "$@"
do
   awk '{print "\" $0 "\","}' < $FILE > $FILE.tmp
   mv $FILE.tmp $FILE
done
```

Comment: `awk` will accept the input file as a command line argument without redirection.

Answer (score 0):

In vi:

```
:%s/^\(.*\)$/"\1",/g
```