# Perl (or something else) - ^M problem

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to add `"` at beginning and `",` at end of each non-empty line of text file in Perl.

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(.+)$/\"$1\",/g' something.txt
```

It adds `"` at beginning of each non-empty line, but i have problem with `",`.

Example input:

```
bla
bla bla
blah
```

That's output i'm getting:

```
"bla
",
"bla bla
",
"blah
",
```

And that's **output i actually want**:

```
"bla",
"bla bla",
"blah",
```

How do I fix this?

Edit:
I opened my output file in vim now (I opened it in kwrite before so it wasn't visible) and I noticed vim shows `^M` before each `",` - I don't know what in code adds this.

Comment: What happens if you just drop the `$` in your search regex?

Comment: Using your example input and UNIX line endings (\n), your code works as indented.

Comment: Mikael: so it's editor issue? i should change mode in kwrite or something?

Comment: Phil, those ^M-s are the windows returns I was talking about; dos2unix will remove them; different editors will add those - usually notepad etc

Comment: ah, sorry. i understand now. i was shocked because i wasn't doing anything on windows with it. maybe program that generated text i'm modifying leaves these windowsy returns. dos2unix works great, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a line ending problem - did you edit the file in windows? Try **dos2unix**

If you don't want to use dos2unix you can match for the \r:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(.+)\r$/\"$1\",/g'
```

The problem is that if you have returns in the file it will match them in .* so you'll get:

```
"bla^M",
"bla bla^M",
"blah^M",
```

Comment: no, i didn't. i only run that script on it, no manual editing.

Comment: you can just match for it - s/\r//g

Answer (score 2):

Your data file must have originated on Windows, which uses CRLF as a line delimiter instead of just LF.  This means your text file looks like this:

```
bla[CR][LF]bla bla[CR][LF]blah[CR][LF]
```

You can verify this by using `od -c something.txt`.

```
$ od -c something.txt
0000000    b   l   a  \r  \n   b   l   a       b   l   a  \r  \n   b   l
0000020    a   h  \r  \n                                                
0000024
```

Under Unix or Linux, it will appear like this:

```
bla\r
bla bla\r
blah\r
```

When perl makes it's substitution, it results in this:

```
"bla\r",
"bla bla\r",
"blah\r",
```

And when you cat the result, you get what you see:

```
"bla
",
"bla bla
",
"blah
",
```

The easy thing to do is to use [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) to convert the line endings to Unix format, then your scripts will behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

On systems that use CRLF text files, Perl uses an IO layer to filter the CRLF to that we only see an LF in our scripts.  However, if you open a CRLF file on a system that does not use CRLF normally, you can enable the CRLF translation in a number of ways.

You can use [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html).  I use the OO interface here because I think it is cleaner, YMMV:

```
use IO::File;

open( my $fh, '<', 'winfile.txt' ) 
    or die "Oh poo - $!\n";

$fh->binmode(':crlf');
```

You can also use a tweaked open:

```
open( my $fh, '<:crlf', 'winfile.txt' ) 
    or die "Oh poo - $!\n";
```

Or for your one-liner you can set the PERLIO environment variable (see [PerlIO](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html)):

```
PERLIO=crlf perl -pi -e 's/^(.+)$/\"$1\",/g' something.txt
```

Of course, this approach will preserve the CRLF line endings in the processed file--which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: no, i don't want to keep these windowsy line endings in this case but i voted you up because it's interesting and may be of use for something else

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.\{1,\}/"&",/'
```

This was asked before [python or bash - adding " at beginning of line and ", at end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688952/)

Comment: +1 Perl was originally conceived as a more advanced sed/awk. B

Comment: well, pixel... it doesn't work. it deletes first letter of each line and substitutes it with ",

Comment: works for me with gnu sed on linux. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

since you want to add at beginning and end, you don't a regex substitution for that simple task.

```
perl -ne 'chomp;print "\"".$_."\",\n"' file
```

Comment: Except that it adds quotes for empty lines too.

Comment: that should be easy to fix. just do a check for empty lines first. I will leave it to OP.